# Allow docker react native app to open in ios simulator

Tags: react-native, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, expo

I was wondering if anyone had a better solution for developing React Native apps in a docker container? ... I dont want to install NPM on my host system so I do it all from docker, the way i do it at the moment is use the `Dockerfile` below and then open it up on my actual physical device using Expo Go ... But i would much rather be able to develop using iOS Simulator ... Is is possible to open a port to be able to do this? Has anyone found a good solution or could improve on the `Dockerfile` i have below;

```
FROM node:current-buster-slim

ARG NODE_ENV=production
ENV NODE_ENV $NODE_ENV

ARG PORT=19006
ENV PORT $PORT
EXPOSE $PORT 19001 19002

ENV NPM_CONFIG_PREFIX=/home/node/.npm-global
ENV PATH /home/node/.npm-global/bin:$PATH
RUN npm i --unsafe-perm --allow-root -g npm@latest expo-cli@latest
RUN npm install -g @expo/ngrok@^4.1.0

RUN mkdir /opt/react_native_app
WORKDIR /opt/react_native_app
ENV PATH /opt/react_native_app/.bin:$PATH
COPY ./package.json ./package-lock.json ./
RUN npm install

WORKDIR /opt/react_native_app/app
COPY ./ .

ENTRYPOINT ["npx", "expo", "start", "--tunnel"]
```

I then run it all by issuing the following;

```
docker run -it --rm -v $(PWD):/app -w /app node npx expo start --tunnel
```

Comment: Installing Node is probably a one-liner with your OS package manager, if you don't already have it installed.  It seems like that will be much easier than trying to do development work in an isolated container.